# script to print lines with 4 words

Tags: unix, sed

I'm starting out with sed, I need to run over the lines of a file, print the lines with exactly 4 words, and in those lines I should print the first word 3 times.

What i mean is, if this file is given:

```
Hello hi 123
if a equals b
you
one abc two three four
dany uri four 123
```

This is the output:

```
if if if a equals b
dany dany dany uri four 123
```

This is what I did:

```
sed `s/\(\<.\+\>\)\(\<.\+\>\)\{3\}/\1/` F1
```

where F1 is an existing file. I was told to put all the \ in so the bash interpreter won't touch it. Here's the script without them:

```
sed 's/(<.+>)(<.+>){3}/\1' F1
```

the error is:

```
./P8.1: line 1: s/(<.+>)(<.+>){3}/1/: No such file or directory sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `F'
```

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd better give a simple line.

Comment: Yes, so the bash interpreter won't change things in my code (like if I write *, it won't replace it with all the files in the working directory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
sed -ne 's/^\(\w\+\)\(\W\+\w\+\)\{3\}$/\1 \1 &/p'
```

If you are using GNU sed, then it's more readable using the `-r` flag like this:

```
sed -nre 's/^(\w+)(\W+\w+){3}$/\1 \1 &/p'
```

Explanation:

- Use the `-n` flag to not print lines by default, only by explicit `p` command in `sed`
- `\w` is a *word character*, `\W` is a non-word character
- `\1` is the matched captured by the first `\(...\)`
- `&` is the entire matched pattern. Since we're matching `^...$` this is the entire original line
- With the `-r` in GNU sed (`-E` in BSD sed), we can simplify `\(....\)` as `(...)` and `\+` as `+` and `\{...\}` as `{...}`

I'm not sure if `\w` and `\W` will work in all systems. If it doesn't work, you can use *something like* `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead of `\w` and `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead of `\W`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

***An Awk Approach you may try***

```
$ cat file      
Hello hi 123
if a equals b
you
one abc two three four
dany uri four 123
```

**Awk examples**

```
$ awk 'NF==4{print $1,$1,$0}' file
if if if a equals b
dany dany dany uri four 123
```

**OR**

```
$ awk '{f = NF == 4 ? 1 : 0; $0 = $1 FS $1 FS $0}f' file
if if if a equals b
dany dany dany uri four 123
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it in sed.

Comment: @shoham You do not have `sed`.  I have not seen any system with only `sed` and no `awk`.  Here is `awk` better then `sed` to do this job.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^(\S+)(\s\S+){3}$/s//\1 \1 &/p' file
```